# Juju and no default VPC on AWS

Tags: juju, default, amazon-ec2, aws

I'm trying to use Juju with AWS but when I bootstrap it says that it cannot set up groups: "No default VPC for this user (VPCIdNotSpecified)".

I have no default VPC on AWS and it appears [it's not trivial](https://serverfault.com/questions/509136/how-do-i-set-a-vpc-in-aws-to-default-vpc-true)  to get it.  There's been [some discussion](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbugs.launchpad.net%2Fbugs%2F1221868&ei=OfR6U8PFBO6e7Aa8moD4Bw&usg=AFQjCNGd2JLXiCoue_UAAazzKngVLwRweA&sig2=1nLobB2T2VFf0Gm0M0Pllg&bvm=bv.67229260,d.ZGU) about this but it doesn't look like it's resolved.

Does anyone know if it is possible to set the VPC in environments.yaml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with juju at the moment, and there are no immediate plans to support custom VPC instead of the default VPC (at least not for the 14.10 release). Juju uses VPC-related AWS APIs now and will increase its reliance on VPC-based EC2 deployments.

What I can advise you is to contact AWS support to restore your default VPC (in case you had one and deleted it) or perhaps sign-up for a new AWS account, as it should come with a default VPC.

Please, file a bug against juju-core as well, so we can keep track of this and have it  considered for future releases. If it affects a lot of people, I'm sure it can be done sooner rather than later.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core

Comment: [Bug #1321442](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1321442)